# jquery animate "onstart" - theory

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

before an animation starts I need to analyze my elements to make sure everything is in the right spot.

I have this working now, but the problem is that when you click the "animate" button too fast then things fall out of place. I can't expect a user to be patient and wait for every animation to complete.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disable the button on animation start, enable it on an animation complete callback.

Comment: I'm already quite versed with `stop` and that wasn't a viable solution. Your solution isn't exactly what I wanted, but it allows me to dodge the "bug".

Answer (score 1):

Before you start animating, you should call [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to interrupt any ongoing and queued animations. Then reset your elements like you do now and start the new animation.

In case it's helpful, `.stop(true, true)` would simply jump to the end of the animation rather than leaving elements in between their start/stop positions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stop(true, true)` to clear the queue and jump to the end.

This will bring the elements to the end state of the previously running animation.

Here

First attribute is to clear queue

Second attribute is to jump to end.

Answer (score 1):

`.animation()` have a undocumented `start` options, use it to make your analyze

```
$('.box').animate({left:100},{
    duration:500,
    start:function(){
        console.log('start');
    },
    complete:function(){
        console.log('end');
    }
});
```